# How to suppress C++ keywords?

Tags: c++

I'm generating C++ code and run into issues when the model being generated from has properties clashing with C++ keywords. I'd prefer the model to stay language agnostic.

I've tried some `#define int ReSeRvEd_int`-hacks local to the generated code but it just feels wrong to allocate other symbols - the problem does not really go away and either case cross referencing between generated code and model becomes more difficult.

Any suggestion how to suppress/hide keywords?

Comment: No, there is no better way. Use `#define`s or change the code generator to not use C++ keywords.

Comment: Your generator should know all reserved words for the language and do mapping.

Comment: You can see how it is done in ICE - they have similar problem https://doc.zeroc.com/ice/3.7/the-slice-language/lexical-rules#id-.LexicalRulesv3.7-IdentifiersThatAreKeywords

Comment: @Slava is the backslash standard c++?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can think of a couple of approaches:

- Add a standard prefix or suffix to all generated tokens. So rather than properties named "steve" and "int" producing variables named `steve` and `int` respectively, they would produce `prop_steve` and `prop_int`.
- Force generated tokens to be capitalized.

Two things that I would *not* do:

- Try to make the parser okay with a property named `int`, as you seem to be trying to do above. In addition to violating the Principle of Least Astonishment, this is not legal.
- Have a hardcoded remapping from, say, "int" to `innt`. Ugly, inconsistent, and (assuming the generated code interfaces with user-written code) forces the user to memorize the remappings.

Comment: Capitalizing generated (internal) tokens is actually a good idea. The model is case-insensitive anyway. And it is easy to convert to all-lowercase should I find that more readable during review.